# ¿Cómo obtener repetidos y no repetidos en un arreglo con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo encontrar el índice de datos repetidos y no repetidos en un `array` he irlos almacenando en otro arreglo con un `push()` en JavaScript?

Tengo el siguiente código, pero el problema es que por cada dato que encuentre repetido me crea un `array` y no debería ser así.

```
Array.prototype.getDuplicates = function() {
  var duplicates = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (duplicates.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
      duplicates[this[i]].push(i);
    } else if (this.lastIndexOf(this[i]) !== i) {
      duplicates[this[i]] = [i];
    }
  }

  return duplicates;
};

console.log([2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1].getDuplicates());
```

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function duplicados(ar) {
        let object = {};
        let result = {};
        result["indices"]=[];
        result["repetidos"]=[];
        result["no_repetidos"]=[];

        ar.forEach(function (item) {
          if(!object[item])
              object[item] = 0;
            object[item] += 1;
        })

        for (var prop in object) {
           if(object[prop] >= 2){
               result["repetidos"].push(prop);
               result["indices"].push(arreglo.indexOf(parseInt(prop)));
          }else{
                result["no_repetidos"].push(prop);
          }
          
        }

        return result;

    }
    let arreglo = [1, 2, -2, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8, 7, 7, 71, 3, 6];
    console.log(duplicados(arreglo));
```

Comment: ¿como obtengo los indices de los que se repiten y de los que no se repiten?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ar=['a','b','c']
var num = ar.indexOf('b'); // esto te va retornar un 1
```

despues podes insertar num a un array y ahi tenes los indices de los elementos